# How can I prevent a Dockerfile instruction from being cached?

Tags: caching, curl, docker, dockerfile

In my `Dockerfile` I use `curl` or `ADD` to download the latest version of an archive like:

```
FROM debian:jessie
...
RUN apt-get install -y curl
...
RUN curl -sL http://example.com/latest/archive.tar.gz --output archive.tar.gz
...
ADD http://example.com/latest/archive2.tar.gz
...
```

The `RUN` statement that uses `curl` or `ADD` creates its own image layer. That will be used as a cache for future executions of `docker build`.

**Question**: How can I disable caching for that instructions?

It would be great to get something like **cache invalidation** working there. E.g. by using [HTTP ETags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) or by querying the *last modified* header field. That would give the possibility to do a quick check based on the HTTP headers to decide whether a cached layer could be used or not.

I know that some dirty tricks could help e.g. executing a download shell script in the `RUN` statement instead. Its filename will be changed before the `docker build` is triggered by our build system. And I could do the HTTP checks inside that script. But then I need to store either the last used *ETag* or the *last modified* to a file somewhere. I am wondering whether there is some more clean and *native* Docker functionality that I could use, here.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A build-time argument can be specified to forcibly break the cache from that step onwards. For example, in your Dockerfile, put

```
ARG CACHE_DATE=not_a_date
```

and then give this argument a fresh value on every new build. The best, of course, is the timestamp.

```
docker build --build-arg CACHE_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S) ...
```

Make sure the value is a string without any spaces, otherwise docker client will falsely take it as multiple arguments.

See a detailed discussion on [Issue 22832](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22832).

Comment: Or better yet, feed it with $RANDOM ?

Comment: With timestamp we can be 100% rest assured that the value will always be unique, besides the timestamp information can be handy if it's going to be used somewhere in the container.

Comment: Haven't followed the new releases of Docker. But the idea behind this solution is to try to provide a new value to break the cache each time the build is run, which can be implemented in lots of ways. As long as long Docker caching mechanism does not change, a similar way can be found.

Comment: A decent random generator should never yield collisions (within the lifespan of the universe), and has an arbitrarily high change frequency.

Comment: FWIW, `ARG CACHE_DATE=` (without `not_a_date`) was sufficient for me.

Comment: This also working with `podman-compose` with `podman` engine rootless, not only with docker. Thanks @RuifengMa !

Answer (score 37):

[docker build --no-cache](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/build/) would invalidate the cache for *all* the commands.

[Dockerfile ADD command](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add) used to have the cache invalidated. Although [it has been improved](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/880#issuecomment-47076896) in recent docker version:

> Docker is supposed to checksum any file added through ADDand then decide if it should use the cache or not.

So if the file added has changed, the cache should be invalidated for the `ADD` command.

---

[Issue 1326](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1326#issuecomment-52304721) mentions other tips:

> This worked.

```
RUN yum -y install firefox #redo
```

> So it looks like Docker will re-run the step (and all the steps below it) if the string I am passing to `RUN` command changes in anyway - **even it's just a comment**.
>
> The docker cache is used only, and only if none of his ancestor has changed (this behavior makes sense, as the next command will add change to the previous layer).
>
> The cache is used if there isn't any character which has changed (so even a space is enough to invalidate a cache).

Comment: Recent docker version? That comment was from over a year ago :)

Comment: @Adr I agree. In "docker time", that seems so long ago.

Comment: Some hint: `RUN yum -y install firefox #redo` will only work with run, as `#redo` is not a dockerfile comment. I accidentally broke stuff using this with e.g. `WORKDIR`...

Answer (score -6):

add `&& exit 0` after a command will invalidate the cache from there.

Example:

`RUN apt-get install -y unzip && exit 0`

Comment: Just tried with Docker version 1.12.0-rc2, it's not working, still cache the instruction