# Private module not updating inside docker

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

I have a Python project in Docker, where I have custom modules from private repos.

The install and use works great, but I can't update it easily.
The package changes (I push new commits to it), but when `docker build` runs next, it will just use the cache, even if I have `--no-cache-dir` and `--force-reinstall` in the `pip` command.
How can I make sure that this package is always pulled from the repo?

```
git+ssh://git@gitea.example.com:10223/Company/Project.git@master#egg=Project
```

Dockerfile relevant parts:

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements ./requirements
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade --force-reinstall -r ./requirements/requirements.txt
```

Comment: what is your current directory when you run `RUN pip install (...)` ? Do you intend to install globally ?

Comment: This is an excellent question, and fortunately it already has an answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/31782220/3216427